# Layout issue with dynamic height of body and footer

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I want to display the footer at the bottom of the page. I have multiple routes and each component is of different height.

If the height of the main component is less than the footer, the footer moves in the middle of the page as shown below.

I tried the with `bottom: 0`, and the footer moves to the end of the page, but when the main content increases it becomes cropped. I'm expecting to push the footer down when content increases.
[image]

```
<BrowserRouter >
   <Navigation />
   <main>
      <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
      <Route path="/test1" component={test1} />
      <Route path="/test2" component={test2} />
      <Route path="/ContactUs" component={ContactUs} />
      <Route path="/AboutUs" component={AboutUs} />
   </main>
   <div class='spacer'></div>
   <Footer />
</BrowserRouter >
```

PS: My main content and footer content height are dynamic, so I'm not able to fix the height of the footer.

Comment: The thread that is linked is kinda useless, because the web has evolved since then. Use `min-height: 100vh` on your body or content container, or solve your issue by using `display: flex` on your body element, and make the content container fill out all the empty space, if here is any.

Comment: i tried min-height:100vh, but it brings scroll when the main content was less. and i want to avoid that. display:flex also not working, just tried that